# ''happiness is only real when shared'' or ''hapiness only real ...''

Tags: syntactic-analysis

When we can avoid to put the verb to be?

In this case are both correct or ''happiness' only real....'' because of the double ss at the end of the word we can avoid to write it down? because the sound is complete

*thank you :)*

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.

"Your happiness matters to me!" he declared.  Works fine. 
"Your happiness is what matters to me!" he declared.  Works okay.
"Your happiness only important thing!" he declared.  Not so much.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use the contraction "happiness'" for "happiness is". In general, you can only use the "'s" suffix in its verbal form on pronouns e.g. "he's", "she's", "it's", "who's".
If you see the "'s" suffix on other words, it generally denotes possession, e.g. "the fox's glove", "the house's porch".

Maybe in spoken English, you could get away with eliding the "is" into the double "s"es, but I've never heard anyone who isn't very drunk pronounce it that way ;) If you did add an apostrophe to the end, because "happiness" is a noun, it would imply possession, which doesn't make much sense.

If you want to avoid the "to be" verb, you could use this construction

> Happiness: only real when shared.

However, in English it's hard to get away with writing a sentence without a verb. Lacking an action, because "happiness" is the subject, it's difficult to get around using "is" without getting weird sentences like the example